# We need an Event!

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about this, courtesy of seeing a "Community Events" link in the mod menu, because wouldn't it be cool to have an "Event" here?

Maybe something like the "World Pentax Day" where on that day, community members go out an take their best photo, the community votes, and the winner owns the site banner for some extended period like a month. I don't know, maybe we could even get the great folks at SE to throw in a t-shirt or something and it becomes an annual thing.

What do people think? Any other ideas?

Comment: I think getting some events rolling is a great idea. It's been talked about before, but we had struggling momentum. You've got a lot of energy, and with that I think it might be more feasible to start events, and have them periodically throughout the year.

Comment: +1 great idea .

Comment: If you've got the energy and time for it, I'd love to see the themed contests restart. I even have a [step-by-step plan](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/a/2654/1943) for how it'd work, just not the time to implement.

Comment: @mattdm - That's a possibility, I think, I just need to see how my time availability looks. For this, though, I was thinking of a bigger splash item.

Comment: @mattdm - I don't have blog privileges that I'm aware of, not sure how that's actually connect to this site (if at all).

Comment: For blog privs @jrista can hook you up, I think.

Comment: Can you give me more ideas what you mean by "event"? What do other sites do for events? Does an event have to relate to the homepage banner?

Comment: Honestly, a weekly critique event on the main site would be nice. Especially if it's on the main site. Single photograph posts, critique in comments, everything is CW. Thread closed one week after it is posted, comments closed 2 weeks after the thread is posted (if that is possible).

Comment: An event can really be anything we want it to be, but if we do something like a contest, the only real point of customization is the banner. Other events could be beer nights, but we're a little scattered. :)

Comment: I created a new Meta question with an [annual event proposal](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/annual-community-event-proposal).

Comment: @mattdm - I think we can swing the themed contest. I had an idea of maybe that being once every 4 weeks or something. Basically, the rolling contest provides most of images, but the theme based contest drives the other week (not withstanding my proposal for an annual big contest). Thoughts?

Comment: Has anyone tried the live chat feature yet?   That might be a good start to a first event.   A live chat event to get the ball rolling?   Check out http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat